# Where i can find MySQL data file

Tags: mysql, debian

Where I can find file with all records from my Database?

I have DB "selloffi_bot" with 1 table "gen" where are ~12.000.000 records. Table size is 1.5GB. I want to copy all data files without mysqldump. Just copy 1:1 from my VPS to my PC.

I checked /var/lib/mysql/selloffi_bot and i found only 2 files

db.opt - 65B
gen.frm - 8620B

[image: phpMyAdmin screen]

Debian 7.0 64-bit minimum

PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

MySQL Version: 5.5.40

Comment: have you tried `show variables like 'datadir'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using InnoDB, it's in the ibdata files. Also see here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80320/where-does-mysql-store-data/80332

Edit: As Isaac notes below, the ibdata files aren't really meant to be portable, so the only reliable thing to do is to dump and load the data.

Comment: This is true (and you're one directory level too deep to see the ibdata files), but you will probably encounter difficulties copying the data directory and ibdata files. They're not designed to just copy between systems.